# Cannot use async in closing method

Tags: c#, wpf

I make a method called `Instance` that allow me to have a single instance of the `Settings` window, like this:

```
    public static async Task<Settings> Instance()
    {
        if (AppWindow == null)
        {
            AppWindow = new Settings();

            AppWindow.Closing += async (x, y) =>
            {
                bool close = await AppWindow.CheckSettings();
                y.cancel = (close) ? true : false;
                AppWindow = null;
            };
        }

        return AppWindow;
    }
```

the CheckSettings have this structure:

```
private async Task<bool> CheckSettings()
{   
     //just as example
    return true;
}
```

the method Instance() tell me that there is no `await` operator inside. Why happen this?

I need to ask also other questions:

1. Can this logic used inside a property instead of `Instance` method? How?
2. Is possible close the window without implement a `Task<bool>`

**UPDATE**

based on the helpful answer and comments on this great community I have edited the method as this (now is a property):

```
    public static Settings Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (AppWindow == null)
            {
                AppWindow = new Settings();

                AppWindow.Closing += async (x, y) =>
                {
                    bool close = await AppWindow.CheckSettings();
                    y.Cancel = close;

                    //AppWindow.Close();
                    //AppWindow = null;
                };
            }

            return AppWindow;
        }
    }
```

the problem is that the `Cancel` does not await the CheckSettings()

Comment: You don't *do* anything `async` so why have it async?

Comment: @nvoigt I need async because inside CheckSettings I have some method of Mahapp framework like await ShowMessageAsync()

Comment: There is no async call inside the Instance() Method, furthermore, afaik async EventHandler's are not practicable for CancelEventHandler, as the event will be called, and continue, before your Handler finished, so setting the Cancel Property will not do much.

Comment: @nvoigt check the update

Answer (score 4):

Set the `Cancel` property to `true` before you call your `async` method:

```
public static Settings Instance
{
    get
    {
        if (AppWindow == null)
        {
            AppWindow = new Settings();
            //attach the event handler
            AppWindow.Closing += AppWindow_Closing;
        }
        return AppWindow;
    }
}

private static async void AppWindow_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;

    //call the async method
    bool close = await AppWindow.CheckSettings();
    if (close)
    {
        AppWindow win = (AppWindow)sender;
        //detach the event handler
        AppWindow.Closing -= AppWindow_Closing;
        //...and close the window immediately
        win.Close();
        AppWindow = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP has no idea whether they want to cancel the closing or not before they call the method.  The whole point of the method is to determine if they should be cancelling the closing of the form.  You now can't ever close this form.

Comment: Yes? The window will only be closed if CheckSettings returns true. What's your point?

Comment: And then it will be cancelled again, and the form will never close.

Comment: No. Because the event handler is detached once the CheckSettings method returns true. The "form" is then closed as expected.

Comment: You should try the code (or at least read it a bit more carefully) before you downvote.

Comment: @mm8 I think your solution is good, I upvoted your answer but I does not have enough rep unfortunately, anyway, when the `win.Close()` line is reached I get this: `cannot set visibility or call show or showdialog after window has closed` do you know exactly why happen this?

Comment: You can't reuse a closed window. You need to create a new instance of the Settings window once it has been closed. My code sample does work.

Comment: @mm8 yep, I'm closing the instance of the sender (win) so should work 'cause is your code

Comment: @FacundoColidio: Please provide a compilable repo of your issue including all relevant classes if you need any further help on this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @mm8 I think my issue is related to `AppWindow` I declared it in this way: `static Settings AppWindow;` why you have casted it?

Comment: I just cast the sender argument to the actual window that tries to close itself. I guess you only have a single instance of AppWindow but I can't really tell.

Comment: @mm8 the `AppWindow` variable in my case only store the `Settings` instance, should I cast as Settings? it's not clear

Comment: AppWindow should be the same as win. So you probably don't even need to cast. Just do AppWindow.Close() instead of win.Close().

Comment: @mm8 are you sure your code working? I get the same error `cannot set visibility or call show or showdialog after window has closed` also adding AppWindow.Close()

Comment: It's working for a normal window. If it's not working in your context, you need to provide an example of what your context really is. Please refer to the link I supplied in one of my previous comment for more information about how to do this.

Comment: @mm8 please could you check this: https://files.fm/u/gm9t7f98 I prepared a working example, you only need to run it thans

Comment: @FacundoColidio: Your example works like a charm on my end provided that you set the Cancel property to true in the event handler as I suggested in my answer and include the MahApps.Metro resource dictionaries in your App.xaml.

Comment: @mm8 this is weird, please read my other question related to this problem, for me, your solution does not work

Comment: When I try to close the `Window` I get the exception `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot set Visibility to Visible or call Show, ShowDialog, Close, or WindowInteropHelper.EnsureHandle while a Window is closing.'` on the `Close()` call.